# A word to describe "won some lost some but I am glad that I lived and that I am here"

Tags: single-word-requests

There are some moments when I reflect my life of the last year, last five years, ten years etc and I sift through the good and the bad, the hardships and the moments of joy, the wins and losses, but feel like I have lived a decent life and feel a little bit satisfied. Is there a word in English or some other language perhaps that describes this emotion ?

I am not sure if I am describing my question enough so please ask me to elaborate if you find it incomplete.

Comment: The tag for single-word-requests does state that you should "include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used".

Comment: I think you’re looking for a kanji character, not an English word.

Comment: @David The kanji that would fit would probably be 感謝 *kansha* which, incidentally, is 2 kanji. However, the closest English equivalent is likely *gratitude* and hence *grateful*

Comment: @psosuna — No, my point is “grateful” or any other word is far too general to convey the idea of such a particular state of mind. It doesn’t in itself indicate anything about the context of the gratitude. I can’t judge your Japanese, but in English you would have to write a prayer.

Comment: @psosuna — Or a song, perhaps. Think Frank Sinatra (if you are old enough).

Comment: @David I did say "the closest equivalent." There's a bit more weight that can't be expressed in English easily. I was also trying to make the point that the Kanji I chose is not one but 2 kanji, meaning, there is probably not a single word or single kanji that can encompass everything that OP is asking for. It is, in essence, a feeling too strong and with too narrow a context to elicit only one word.

Comment: @psosuna — I’d be interested to have the kanji explained. It’s off-topic, but then it’s only a comment.

Comment: @David Explaining this is complicated but I can take a stab at it. You see, Japanese culture centers around humility. To be grateful for something is to want to apologize for what's undeserved. So the two work as such: 感 *kan* is *feelings, sensations, emotions*, 謝 *sha* is *apology, thanks, refusal*. Some of the side meanings don't quite make up the word when it comes together as 感謝 *kansha* to mean *gratitude* but they paint the periphery. 感謝 *kansha* then is *to feel greatly humbled and appreciative of what has been given to you despite your circumstances*, but even this does no justice.

Comment: @David Japanese people tend to view material and immaterial goods equally as being bestowed. Life experiences included. So to speak, they will also express 感謝 *kansha* about having the opportunities to have experienced things, not just what they receive physically. In other words, it applies in OP's case: OP is thankful for life's ups and downs and is glad to be on the receiving end and glad to be alive. That's about as 感謝 *kansha* as it gets -- 今まで行った経験を*感謝*しています。- *ima made okonatta keiken wo kansha shite imasu.* - *I'm **grateful** for the experiences I've had until now.*

Comment: @David I should add, my Japanese is quite terrible, I would not be surprised if a native speaker stumbled across this and gave me a scolding, haha.

Comment: @psosuna — Thanks. Just back from a visit to Japan travelling with my son has been working for about a year and a half. So I was interested in his approach to kanji in addition to his command of the much simpler (but still not easy) hiragana. Perhaps I'll test him on this ;-)

Comment: 感謝 *kansha* would be a tough one for a 2nd year learner to explain. If you want more appropriate quiz material, have a look at [this.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/why-is-%e4%b8%80%e6%97%a5-tsuitachi/53069#53069)

Answer (score 0):

[Appreciative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/appreciative) is an accurate descriptor for what you're feeling.

> showing that you understand how good something is, or are grateful for something

-Cambridge Online

Although grateful is included in the definition for appreciative, it could also fit.